# Double Integral Help $(x^2+y^2+a^2)^{-2} dx \, dy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

Hi I'm currently revising for a maths module that I am taking as part of my physics degree.

All was going well until I hit a dead-end with this integral, any ideas how to evaluate it?

$$
\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}  \frac{dx~dy}{(x^2 + y^2 + a^2)^2}
$$

---

I tried substituting in 2D polar coordinates to get:
$$
\int^{2 \pi}_{0} \int^{+\infty}_{0}  \frac{r~dr~d\theta}{(r^2 + a^2)^2}
$$
From here I thought of substituting in: $$ r = a~\tan(u)  \Rightarrow dr = a~\sec^2(u)~du $$ This gives: $$
\int^{2 \pi}_{0} \int^{\frac{+\pi}{2}}_{\frac{-\pi}{2}}  \frac{a ~\tan(u)~\sec^2(u) ~ ~du~d\theta}{a^4~\sec^4(u)} = \frac{1}{a^3}\int^{2 \pi}_{0} \int^{\frac{+\pi}{2}}_{\frac{-\pi}{2}}  \frac{\tan(u) ~ ~du~d\theta}{\sec^2(u)}
$$

From here I can't see where to go. Am I on the right track here or have I just overcomplicated this problem?

Thanks!
Sean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By evaluating the iterated integrals separately, the hard part is computing

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{r dr}{(r^2 + a^2)^2}$$

Susbstituting $u = r^2 + a^2$ leads to an elementary integral.